# check if dates are not within range before saving in yii

Tags: validation, yii

how can i check if the dates posted in user's form exist in a range before saving? It's suppose to check different scenario date ranges. Below is just one of them. If it doesn't fall into range, it then posts.

is there a better way to do this?

```
    $model = Table::model();
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    //this is where i don't know how to get the values ($start,$end) from user before posting

    $criteria->addCondition('start_date < '.$start);
    $criteria->addCondition('end_date > '.$end);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create custom validation function :

In rules add : this rules will work for both insert and update.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('dateField', 'myCheckdate',),
    );
}
```

In your custom validation function , you can apply your code to check the date range

```
 public function myCheckdate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())
        {
            if(Condition == false) // place your condition here
            {
                $this->addError($attribute,'The date is incorrect.');
            }
        }
    }
```